# How to Display All Categories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Am trying to display all the category in the database on single post blade, however, am also display five out the category in the database as my navigation menu. I am not sure maybe its the loop I am using as I keep getting five categories instead of all categories.

```php
public function index()
{
    return view('index')->with('title', Setting::first()->site_name)
        ->with('categories', Category::take(5)->get())
        ->with('first_post', Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first())
        ->with('second_post', Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->get()->first())
        ->with('third_post', Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(2)->take(1)->get()->first())
        ->with('wordpress', Category::find(4))
        ->with('laravel', Category::find(3))
        ->with('settings', Setting::first());
}
```

Here is the code for my single post controller

```php
public function singlePost($slug)
{
    $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $next_id = Post::where('id', '>', $post->id)->min('id');
    $prev_id = Post::where('id', '<', $post->id)->max('id');

    return view('single')->with('post', $post)
        ->with('title', $post->title)
        ->with('settings', Setting::first())
        ->with('categories', Category::all())
        ->with('next', Post::find($next_id))
        ->with('prev', Post::find($prev_id))
        ->with('tags', Tag::all())
        ->with('first_post', Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first())
        ->with('second_post', Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->get()->first())
        ->with('third_post', Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(2)->take(1)->get()->first());
}
```

This is how I passed the value in the single.blade.php

```php
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <div class="post-category-wrap">
        <div class="category-post-item">
            <!-- <span class="post-count">168</span> -->
            <a href="{‌{route('category.single', ['id' => $category->slug])}}" class="category-title">{‌{$category->name}}
                <i class="seoicon-right-arrow"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What are you under the impression `take(5)` does?

Comment: take(5) returns 5 categories from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the var name in index query for 'categories'. Something like 
`->with('categories_to_navigation', Category::take(5)->get())`. 
If the view `single.blade.php` extend `index.blade.php` this var names are being overwritten.

Comment: Problem solved I actually did not think of it that way. thank you @juan.